# UICollectionView Cells Not Showing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got this bit of code, and I can't get the cells to show up. I've tried setting a background colour to see if they were showing up and it was just the images within them that weren't appearing, but it seems that the cells aren't showing up at all.

Edit: This is the full code, with everything from other elements as well (Most things are commented out)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

//Things in the collection cell
class AvatarCollectiveCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var AvatarImage: UIImageView!

}

class Avatar: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

// Collection View Within View Controller
@IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!

// Avatar Images

var AvatarImages = ["Avacado", "Bear", "Cow", "Carrot", "Dolphin", "Dinosaur", "Elephant", "Flamingo", "Fox", "Hippo", "Jellyfish", "Moose", "Monkey", "Octopus", "Pig", "Panda", "Parrot", "Pumpkin", "Popcorn", "Penguin", "Platypus", "Sheep", "Sloth", "Shark", "Wolf"]
//AvatarCollectionView.reloaddata()
//
// CollectionView.dataSource = self
//CollectionView.delegate = self
//UICollectionView.reloadData()
// CollectionView.reloadData()

// Create Cells
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return AvatarImages.count //Number of Images
}


// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AvatarCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! AvatarCollectiveCell
    let Avatars = AvatarImages[indexPath.item]




    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    //cell.BookCover.image = UIImage(named: arrayBookImages[indexPath.item])
    cell.AvatarImage.image = UIImage(named: AvatarImages[indexPath.item-1])
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // make cell more visible in our example project

    return cell
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // USERNAME DISPLAY BEGINS
    /*
     //reload the data for the collection view
     //NameDisplay.reloadData()

     guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
     return
     }

     //getting the managed context where the entity we need is
     let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

     //make fetch request
     let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "UserInfo", attributeName: "name")


     //try to fetch the entity we need, else print error
     do {
     Username = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
     } catch let error as NSError {
     print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
     }*/
    //USERNAME DISPLAY ENDS


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    //  CollectionView.dataSource = self
    //   CollectionView.delegate = self
    //super.viewDidLoad()
    // Avatar.collectionView?.register(AvatarCollectiveCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: ObjectIdentifier)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

var Username:String = ""
@IBOutlet weak var NameDisplay: UILabel!
/*
 // MARK: - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */
```

}

*** Note: Errors were fixed by changing the module of the view controller***

Error it crashes with:

2017-05-14 23:27:49.905819 FInal Project[25556:734502] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/student/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/265EA47F-07A6-47C7-A6B4-5E62D37E72BA/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-05-14 23:27:49.990769 FInal Project[25556:734502] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2017-05-14 23:27:55.065654 FInal Project[25556:734502] [Common] _BSMachError: port 7103; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
2017-05-14 23:27:55.066446 FInal Project[25556:734502] [Common] _BSMachError: port 7103; (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable to deallocate send right"
12345abcde
in 
Out 
2017-05-14 23:29:01.246 FInal Project[25556:734502] Unknown class AvatarCollectiveCell in Interface Builder file.
2017-05-14 23:29:01.824 FInal Project[25556:734502] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key AvatarImage.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104948d4b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103f8921e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104948c99 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000103a979df -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000105544375 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 173
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010588e79e -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001048ed9e0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010588d122 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000105dd2012 -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 1094
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000105dd28ea -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 169
    10  FInal Project                       0x00000001039509fb _TFC13FInal_Project6Avatar14collectionViewfTCSo16UICollectionView13cellForItemAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 171
    11  FInal Project                       0x0000000103950db7 _TToFC13FInal_Project6Avatar14collectionViewfTCSo16UICollectionView13cellForItemAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 87
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000105dbd75f -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 467
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000105dbd586 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 35
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000105dc2a5e -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4803
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000105dc8725 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 313
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000105544ab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ae3fbf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ae33440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ae332be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010adc1318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010adee3ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001054aa7f0 _afterCACommitHandler + 346
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001048ed267 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001048ed1d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001048d1f8e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001048d1884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a64ca6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010547fc68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    29  FInal Project                       0x00000001039495bf main + 111
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010877268d start + 1
    31  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Edits;

2017-05-15 06:24:55.693709 FInal Project[32230:909344] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/student/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/265EA47F-07A6-47C7-A6B4-5E62D37E72BA/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-05-15 06:24:55.694415 FInal Project[32230:909344] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2017-05-15 06:25:01.292524 FInal Project[32230:909344] [Common] _BSMachError: port 7403; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
2017-05-15 06:25:01.293292 FInal Project[32230:909344] [Common] _BSMachError: port 7403; (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable to deallocate send right"
12345abcde
in 
Out 
2017-05-15 06:25:11.059 FInal Project[32230:909344] Unknown class AvatarCollectiveCell in Interface Builder file.
2017-05-15 06:25:11.595 FInal Project[32230:909344] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key AvatarImage.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c26d4b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010326721e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c26c99 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000102d759df -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000104822375 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 173
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000104b6c79e -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103bcb9e0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000104b6b122 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001050b0012 -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 1094
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001050b08ea -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 169
    10  FInal Project                       0x0000000102c2eafb _TFC13FInal_Project6Avatar14collectionViewfTCSo16UICollectionView13cellForItemAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 171
    11  FInal Project                       0x0000000102c2eeb7 _TToFC13FInal_Project6Avatar14collectionViewfTCSo16UICollectionView13cellForItemAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 87
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010509b75f -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 467
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010509b586 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 35
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001050a0a5e -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4803
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001050a6725 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 313
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000104822ab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a1abbf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a19f440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a19f2be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a12d318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a15a3ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001047887f0 _afterCACommitHandler + 346
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103bcb267 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103bcb1d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103baff8e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103baf884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001099b8a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010475dc68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    29  FInal Project                       0x0000000102c276bf main + 111
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107a5068d start + 1
    31  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: check this answer for the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v

Comment: select your view controller and remove the objects that have no outlets

Comment: Thank you! It's now crashing with the error added to the original post

Comment: AvatarImage has a wrong outlet check on your controller

Comment: The only outlet it has is one to the collective cell, and if I remove it, I get errors within the code

Comment: wait, let me create a sample will get back to you.

Comment: @R.R if you copy/pasted code from the answers, you might need to reconnect the IBOutlets.

Comment: I got it! Thank you! Turned out that the module of the view controller was incorrect. Changing it solved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set the collection view's datasource and delegate? Your view controller doesn't seem to implement those protocols.

```
class Avatar: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    // Collection View Within View Controller
    @IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!

    // Avatar Images

    var AvatarImages = ["Avacado", "Bear", "Cow", "Carrot", "Dolphin", "Dinosaur", "Elephant", "Flamingo", "Fox", "Hippo", "Jellyfish", "Moose", "Monkey", "Octopus", "Pig", "Panda", "Parrot", "Pumpkin", "Popcorn", "Penguin", "Platypus", "Sheep", "Sloth", "Shark", "Wolf"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       CollectionView.dataSource = self
       CollectionView.delegate = self
       // other setup stuff if you need it...
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can also do this from the storyboard by Ctrl-dragging from the collection view to the view controller. (You still have to declare the `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocols after your class name/`UIViewController`.)

[image]
[image]

**Edit based on full code**

The following compiles for me with no errors, and I think is at least the gist of what you want. (I did not uncomment anything except what was relevant to this answer, i.e. anything outside of `viewDidLoad`.)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

//Things in the collection cell
class AvatarCollectiveCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var AvatarImage: UIImageView!
}

class Avatar: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


    // Collection View Within View Controller
    @IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!

    // Avatar Images

    var AvatarImages = ["Avacado", "Bear", "Cow", "Carrot", "Dolphin", "Dinosaur", "Elephant", "Flamingo", "Fox", "Hippo", "Jellyfish", "Moose", "Monkey", "Octopus", "Pig", "Panda", "Parrot", "Pumpkin", "Popcorn", "Penguin", "Platypus", "Sheep", "Sloth", "Shark", "Wolf"]

    // Create Cells
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return AvatarImages.count //Number of Images
    }


    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AvatarCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! AvatarCollectiveCell
        let Avatars = AvatarImages[indexPath.item]




        // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        //cell.BookCover.image = UIImage(named: arrayBookImages[indexPath.item])
        cell.AvatarImage.image = UIImage(named: AvatarImages[indexPath.item-1])
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // make cell more visible in our example project

        return cell
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // USERNAME DISPLAY BEGINS
        /*
        //reload the data for the collection view
        //NameDisplay.reloadData()

         guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
             return
         }

         //getting the managed context where the entity we need is
         let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

         //make fetch request
         let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "UserInfo", attributeName: "name")


         //try to fetch the entity we need, else print error
         do {
             Username = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
         } catch let error as NSError {
             print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
         }*/
        //USERNAME DISPLAY ENDS


    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        CollectionView.dataSource = self
        CollectionView.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var Username:String = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var NameDisplay: UILabel!
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: I implemented that piece of code and am getting an error saying "Expected declaration"

Comment: Where did you put it? It compiles for me. Make sure that the two lines that set the delegate and datasource are _inside_ `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I've tried it again and I'm getting "Cannot assign type "Avatar" to UICollectionViewDataSource?"

Comment: Does your Avatar class declaration match the first line of that code? `class Avatar: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {`?

Comment: The class declaration is ' class Avatar: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {' and I'm getting the error "Expected Declaration" on CollectionVIew.datasource = self

Comment: Could you paste the full code of your Avatar class after you made the changes somewhere? (In an edit to the question or a pastebin, etc.) It's hard to say what's going on without more information.

Comment: Edited based on the updated question, hopefully that helps a bit.

Comment: I get the error "Undeclared Type AvatarCollectiveCell" on let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AvatarCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! AvatarCollectiveCell

Comment: Right, sorry, I only copied the `Avatar` class from that code snippet since that's the only thing that needs to change. You would still need the `AvatarCollectiveCell` class from your original code.

Comment: Thank you! It compiles, but when I get to the screen, it crashes with the error I added to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
self.collectionView?.register(AvatarCollectiveCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that UICollectionView delegates functions are not calling. Add a breakpoint to UICollectionView delegate functions that are,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

and

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

If that's the case just add  protocols, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate as mentioned below.

```
class Avatar: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{ // Your code here}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check those points

1. Table view constraints
2. Delegate and datasource has been connected or not
3. Check if source array has been cleaned somewhere .
4. If still not appearing then set background color of table view and tableviewcell to test thir appearence.
   5 . still not appearing then clear derived data and clean the project them emplty trash .and run again.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you are not reloading the collection view at all. If you could add the following in ViewDidLoad()

```
var AvatarImages = ["Avacado", "Bear", "Cow", "Carrot", "Dolphin", "Dinosaur", "Elephant", "Flamingo", "Fox", "Hippo", "Jellyfish", "Moose", "Monkey", "Octopus", "Pig", "Panda", "Parrot", "Pumpkin", "Popcorn", "Penguin", "Platypus", "Sheep", "Sloth", "Shark", "Wolf"]

UICollectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: What is this error related two. Could you provide more information ?

Comment: Could you try CollectionView.reloadData() instead

Comment: It's telling me that CollectionView and UICollectionView need a declaration

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath `.reloadData()` has to be called on the instance of the collection view, not on the `UICollectionView` type itself...

Comment: no need to reload data for the first time in such scenario.